# React.js : how to get child component state data (blob) using react-audio-recorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

i want to get recorded i'm want to get wav blob data `state.audioData` from `<AudioRecoder/>` component for sending it to server.

i notice other state data can access well, but `state.audioData` is not.

here is my code.

```
import AudioRecorder from 'react-audio-recorder';
class Test extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handlClick.bind(this);
  }

  handlClick(){
    var binary = [];
    binary.push(this.refs.child.state.auidoData);

    window.console.log("audioData :" + this.refs.child.state.auidoData);
    window.console.log("initialAudio :" + this.refs.child.props.initialAudio);
    window.console.log("isPlaying :" + this.refs.child.state.isPlaying);
    window.console.log("binary :" + binary);

    var blob =  new Blob(binary, {type: "audio/wav"});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    window.console.log(url);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <AudioRecorder ref="child"/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
        <div id="json"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Test;
```

after recording, when i click "click" button, console log AudioRecorder's states..

below is log result

> audioData :undefined
>
> initialAudio :undefined
>
> isPlaying :false
>
> binary :
>
> blob:http://localhost:3000/ac26bd3e-f1c7-43f2-a2ea-769a3e79cb23

in addtion, below is [react-audio-recorder link](https://github.com/danrouse/react-audio-recorder/tree/master/src).

Comment: maybe a typo of having `auidoData` instead of `audioData` ?

Comment: @Dane ah... i missed typing error.. thanks!!